# How sbt knows to look into the the app folder for source codes in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

SBT document says

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html

sbt will find the following automatically:

```
Sources in the base directory
Sources in src/main/scala or src/main/java
Tests in src/test/scala or src/test/java
Data files in src/main/resources or src/test/resources
jars in lib
```

But playframwwork, the source codes are not in ../main folder. It is in ../app folder.

How sbt knows that look for source codes in ../app folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I got the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework has been developed by wrapping out sbt in some custom ways (Play SBT plugin).   So referring only sbt documentation will not help.

You can find [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy)  documentation which explains the anatomy of a Play app. So as it explains

> The app directory contains all executable artifacts: Java and Scala
>   source code, templates and compiled assets’ sources.

Answer (score 4):

Overriding of SBT's default build settings are defined in the SBT plugins for Play (Scala and Java).

eg. in your Play project's `build.sbt` you will have the plugin enabled thus:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

(for the Scala plugin in this example).

The above plugin will override some of the default settings defined by SBT for Play.

The [SBT docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html) also provide some details on how SBT plugins can override default settings.

You can see the gritty details in the source for the [Scala plugin here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt).